# VideoView in a fragment is null during orientationchange

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview, onpause

I have a video view in my fragment. When the video is playing and I change the orientation it throws null pointer exception in frgament onPause() where I'm pausing the videview. This problem did not occur previously when the video view was attached to an activity. Recently I had to change the activity to fragment and getting the exception from then.

video.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fullScreenContainer">
    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:id="@+id/dummySurfaceView"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

This is my fragment onPause()

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (videoView != null) {
        videoView.pausePlayer();
    }
}
```

**videoView** is an object of the class **Video** that extend RelativeLayout which has `VideoView vidPlayer` in it

Video.java

```
public void pausePlayer() {
    isPaused = true;
    vidPlayer.pause();
    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_play);
    controlsManager.cancelHideTimer();
}
```

So, This is the structure ->

```
 ___________________________________
|      ** MyFragment.java **        | 
|  _______________________________  |
| |       ** Video.java **        | |
| |  ___________________________  | |
| | |                           | | |
| | |  **VideoView vidPlayer**  | | |
| | |___________________________| | |
| |                               | |
| |_______________________________| |
|                                   |  
|___________________________________|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this add on the manifest on your activity :

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

and in your activity , you have to add the code below :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls 

}
```

Comment: i would suggest u only work with landscape orientation in your videos that would solve your problem.
use  android :Orientation=”landscape” in the manifest in your videoPlayer Activity. 
otherwise you need to put some code in on configurationChanged not only the code that i posted.
in my case i'm saving the configuration of my drawer with 
mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
try vidPlayer.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); not sure it works
Hope this helps =)
and don't forget to vote and choose my answer if you end up using it.